# Making a siyum on a chelek of the Rambam

Tags: rambam, nine-days, siyum, taanis-bechoros

Is making a siyum on a chelek (section) of the Rambam good enough to absolve one from fasting taanis bechoros, or allowing one to eat meat during the nine days?

I have never seen someone make a siyum on a chelek of the Rambam like seder Zamanim for example. Has anyone seen this before?

On a side note, the Rambam himself writes at the end of each topic in a seder brich rachmanh dsayon.

Comment: "I have never seen someone make a siyum on a chelek of the Rambam like seder Zamanim for example. Has anyone seen this before?" Yes, although I'm not sure that helps answer this question.

Answer (score 3):

Rav Meir Mazuz in Mekor Neeman page.109 was asked this question and he answered that if one finishes one of the books(Maadah,Ahava...) then it's considered a siyum.  He brings the Shu"t HaRashbash siman 52 that one who learns halchos from the Rambam every single day is muvtach that he is a ben olam habaah.

Answer (score 1):

In Guidelines by Rabbi Elozor Barclay and Rabbi Yitzchok Jaeger, both for the 3 Weeks and for Pesach, they say that to make a siyum that permits meat & wine in the first case or breaking the fast Erev Pesach, it must be on one of the following:

1. A seder of Mishnayot (Zeraim, Moed, etc)
2. A masechet of Gemara
3. A sefer of Tanach learned b'iyun (which they do not define)
4. A chelek of Shulchan Aruch

So, at least according to them, no, a chelek of the Mishneh Torah will not suffice.

Comment: interesting,  what is the difference between a chelek of SA and a chelek of Rambam.?

Comment: It's pashut that it's just not common amongst all Jews to go through Rambam like that, that's why they didn't include it.

Comment: I'm sure by chabad it's siyum acceptable

Comment: @FalseMessiah, do you know more people who have finished a chelek of Mishneh Torah or who have finished a chelek of Shulchan Aruch?  If you claim Mishneh Torah is not listed because it is uncommon, all the moreso Shulchan Aruch.

Comment: Isn't there a well-known maaseh from R' Moshe Feinstein z"l where he said to make a siyum on one blatt of gemara, for someone for whom that was a tremendous effort?

Comment: @MichoelR, I too have heard that story.  One can make a chiluk between a siyum to eat meat in 9 days/break fast of first born on the one hand and a siyum to make the learner feel good on the other.  Not taking a position on the answer, but the maaseh is not a clear ra'ayah.